# Fineuploader - Different Size Thumbnails and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, fine-uploader

I have a Wordpress based classified site.

1. Does Fineuploader capable of creating pre configured thumbnails from source image WITH watermark image?
   For eg I need to create thumbnails that has widths 135x***, 150x***, 300x***, 480x***, 1024x***.
   Except source images, all these thumbnails should be watermarked with my site logo
2. Is it possible to integrate this with Wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No. If you want to generate watermarks, you'll need to do that server-side.
2. Yes

Comment: thanks for the reply. for question 01, by "no" did you mean I can't generate thumbnails or I can't generate thumbnails with watermarks?